# Getting 400 Bad request Error when trying to open posts after updating to wordpress 5.0

Tags: permalinks, updates, post-content

I have some Wordpress blogs and after updating to Wordpress 5.0, I am getting same error behavior on them.
Now When I open the URL of some of the posts, I am getting 400 Bad request error and on some of them there is no error, but the content doesn't render.
I've tried to change permalink format and change it back to the first type (post name) as suggested in a few questions in similar problems, but it didn't work.

**EDIT**

If I choose the default permalink pattern (?p=123) The error will fix, but I'll lose all of my links.

Comment: Have you updated DB? Try resave permalinks, too.

Comment: If you meant using `/wp-admin/upgrade.php`, I've tried that but It says that your database is up to date.